# Google Calendar API "Calendar usage limits exceeded."

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

we have an application that takes patient's data and set up an appointment according to it. That appt can then be carried over to google calendar via Google calendar API
everything have been working fine until I started receiving this error.

```
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "quotaExceeded",
    "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
 }
```

we have been sending API request to enter the appointment event to multiple google calendars 8 to be precise.

I don't get why is my limit exceeding when on developer console it is showing me that my current usage percentage is still low.
I'm still a beginner to this so please help me in this matter.

I had tried sending a request to google to increase my limit per user from 600 to 3000.

All I can find on internet is that I have to buy a billing account to get access to other resources.

Comment: If you have sent a request to increase your quota then the only thing to do is wait and see if you get an increase.    You dont need to enable billing for the Google Calendar api.

Comment: How long do I have to wait 
its been 4 days.

Comment: test it a couple of times a day you may not get any email when it's activated.    It can take weeks it depends on how backed up the team is

Comment: It would be best if you wait or contact Google Workspace support if possible, you would need to make sure to properly document the error and what is quota has been hit, the other reason of the error could be that you are using a brand new Google Workspace account and you could be affected by the trial limits.